# Using MySQLdb to return values - Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a table called `coords` and it is defined as:

```
mysql> describe coords;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| location  | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL             |                |
| latitude  | float(20,14) | YES  |     | 0.00000000000000 |                |
| longitude | float(20,14) | YES  |     | 0.00000000000000 |                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using the `MySQLdb` import in my Python script. The purpose of this table is to store (as you can guess, but for clarity) location coordinates (but only when I do not have the coordinates already for a particular location).

I will be querying this table in my Python program to see if I already have coordinates for a pre-requested location. I'm doing this to speed up the use of the `geopy` package that interrogates Google's Geolocation Service.

How do I store the returned floats that correspond to a location? So far I have the following:

```
myVar = cur.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM coords WHERE location ='" + jobLocation + "';")
if myVar == 1:
    print(cur.fetchone())
else:
    try:
        _place, (_lat, _lon) = geos.geocode(jobLocation, region='GB', exactly_one=False)
        print("%s: %.5f, %.5f" % _place, (_lat, _lon))
    except ValueError as err:
       print(err)
```

The code works (well, not really...) but I have no idea of how to get the returned coordinates into separate float variables.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

When you do `cur.fetchone()`, you need to store the result somewhere:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
print row[0], row[1]
```

Now `row[0]` will contain the latitude, and row[1] the longitude.

If you do this when connecting:

```
cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

you can then use a dictionary to refer to the columns by name:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
print row["latitude"], row["longitude"]
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer, so that other users know that it worked and that the question has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent answer.  It is unfortunate the answer isn't in the official docs.